# Cypress - Write a file everytime the url changes

Tags: cypress

I am running a cypress test, in which I visit a url that has many redirects.
I wish to get all redirects and write them to a file.

Doing this code works somehow

```
describe(`Test Offer URL`, () => {
    let urls = [];
    it(`Visits the offer url ${Cypress.env(
        "offer_url"
    )} with a pre-defined user agent of ${userAgent}`, () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env("offer_url"), {
            headers: { "user-agent": userAgent },
        });

        cy.on("url:changed", (url) => {
            urls.push(url);
        });

        cy.log(urls);
    });

     after(() => {
        cy.writeFile("cypress/results/offers.json", {
            baseUrl: Cypress.env("offer_url"),
            userAgent,
            redirectUrls: urls,
        });
    }); 
});
```

so with this code `cy.on("url:changed", (url) => { urls.push(url);});`

I am able to get all the needed urls, I can check this with `cy.log(urls)`
But when i write the file I wont have them all

I thought to run the `cy.writeFile()` function inside of the url onChange trigger, but I get an error :

[image]

I tried chaining with a `.then(() => cy.writeFile())` but it will only write the file one time

Any clues of how I could resolve this.

Comment: I had a similar problem with cypress v 7.+ with code that is working perfect on 6.8 and reoirted it to cypress support. Try downgrading to 6.8

Comment: Downgrading doesn't fix it

Comment: Try doing it in one last `It`, instead of `after block` since i suppose it counts them as 1 string of code and that is the problem

Comment: @RosenMihaylov  No unfortunately this doesn't solve it. It doesn't wait to finish all redirects before running the last `it`

Comment: To wait for them you should do some assertion after the redirect or some wait time. For random redirects I usually put a 4 seconds wait time to be sure the page has finished loading.

Comment: Yeah sure its a solution to add a `cy.wait()` but really not optimal as I have no idea of the number of redirects it could be 3 like 8. And the goal would be executing the test the quickest possible, so adding a hard coded wait time doesn't seem ideal

Comment: May be try something similar to JQ document ready - to assert the page load